# Binding const member in code behind from xaml in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, bind, uid

Is there any good way to bind a property to a const value in codebehind?

When I use ComboBox, I usually do this way in xaml and code behind:

XAML:

```
<ComboBox Name="cbBuz">
   <ComboBoxItem Content="foo" Uid="foo" IsSelected="true" />
   <ComboBoxItem Content="bar" Uid="bar" />
</ComboBox>
```

Codebehind:

```
ComboBoxItem item = cbBuz.GetSelectedItem();
switch (item.Uid)
{
    case "foo":  ... break;
    case "bar":  ... break;
}
```

The reason why I chose this way is following:

- For localization purpose, Content string should not be used to determine which item is selected during saving and loading a last selected item.
- For simplicity, XAML and code-behind should be connected internal identifier (In this case, Uid).  So that, XAML and Code-behind can be maintained separately.

However, maintenance-wise, the internal identifier should be defined in one-place like this:

```
//IDs
public const string ID_foo = "foo";
public const string ID_bar = "bar";

...

//
switch (item.Uid)
{
    case ID_foo:  ... break;
    case ID_bar:  ... break;
}
```

The problem is seemingly property cannot be const value, so there's no way to bind ID_foo and ID_bar to Uid of ComboBoxItem like this:

```
//If ID_foo and ID_bar are properties, this will work.
<ComboBox Name="cbBuz">
   <ComboBoxItem Content="foo" Uid="{Binding ID_foo}" IsSelected="true" />
   <ComboBoxItem Content="bar" Uid="{Binding ID_bar}" />
</ComboBox>
```

So, I want to know how to solve this issue.
Or, is there any better way to implement it.  It would be nice, too.

Best,

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You would be better off using the [StaticExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.staticextension.aspx), like so:

```
Uid="{x:Static local:YourClass.ID_foo}"
```

Where local is an xmlns alias for the C# namespace of your class. More information can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742135.aspx).

The problem with using Binding is you are adding a lot overhead for something that will never change. The binding will attempt to monitor your property. Also, there are [known "leaks"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/938416) with using a Binding with a non-dependency property on an object that don't implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I wanted!  Also, the information related to leak and overhead is really useful.

Comment: Pro tip: when the constant is a number, make sure the types match.  I tried with an int and tried to set a System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Height (a double) in XAML, and it gave me a XamlParseException:

"'23' is not a valid value for property 'Height'."

Comment: Another important note is that the constant needs to be `internal` or `public`. Otherwise there is a XamlC error. The relationship of Xaml and Xaml.cs differs from other classes marked as `partial` (at least for Xamarin.Forms, assume for WPF / MAUI too).

Answer (score 2):

You need to make a property that returns the constant (defined in a const), ie:

```
private const string ID_Foo = "foo";
public string FooId
{
   get { return ID_Foo; }
}
```

Once this is in a property, it will be usable via binding.

Comment: Oh, that's right.  Is there any way to make this shorter?  I mean if it's C++, we can use #define to make macro, but we can't.  I am wondering IValueConverter and Enum could make this shorter when  adding new Uid to ComboBox, not in terms of a volume of whole code.

Comment: @Aki24x: You could potentially do this via an IValueConverter and specifying a value in XAML as a constant (not via binding), instead.  That would allow a single IValueConverter to do a lookup somehow, but you'd need something for it to look up, ie: a name in a dictionary, or use an enum, or...